# Z-Order with Java Swing Components

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have been used **setComponentZOrder(Component com,int index)** for JPanel(panel1) shown as below

```
panel1.setComponentZOrder(panel2, 0);
```

Here panel2 is my second panel. Now it is shown panel2 instead of panel1.  I want to rearrange panel1 as original panel1. How to do it?

Comment: You've added `panel2` to `panel1`?  `panel2` will always appear over `panel1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZOrder is used to control the order in which child components are painted on a parent component.

If you want to display panel1, in the frame instead of panel2, then you should not be playing with ZOrder.

Instead you should be using layout managers. Specifically you should be using a `CardLayout` on a parent panel and then you add panel1 and panel2 to this panel. Then you can use the `CardLayout` to swap panels.

The basics of using a CardLayout is:

```
JPanel parent = new JPanel( new CardLayout() );
JPanel child1 = new JPanel();
JPanel child2 = new JPanel();
parent.add(child1, "child1");
parent.add(child2, "child2");
```

Then when you want to display a different panel you use code like:

```
CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(parent.getLayout());
cl.show(parent, "child2");
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.